# Some ./gradlew commands are holding memory (through java processes)

Tags: android, gradle, memory, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

I perceived that when I run a `./gradlew` task, after the task is done, the system still holds the memory used.

Example:

- Initial memory usage:
  [image]
- After I run a `./gradlew testBuildVariant1UnitTest` task:
  [image]
  and a new Java process is created consuming gbs of memory
- After I run a second `./gradlew testBuildVariant2UnitTest` task:
  [image]
  and a new Java process is created consuming gbs of memory

---

The memory is not released until I kill the `java` processes manually or run the following command:

```
./gradlew --stop
```

---

**Is this the expected behavior? Is there something I can do to release the memory automatically after a `./gradlew` task is run?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is expected, it is caused by the [Gradle Daemon](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html)

> Gradle runs on the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) and uses several
> supporting libraries that require a non-trivial initialization time.
> As a result, it can sometimes seem a little slow to start. The
> solution to this problem is the Gradle Daemon: a long-lived background
> process that executes your builds much more quickly than would
> otherwise be the case.

Although, the size of the retained memory looks concerning.

Have a look at [How to disable the Daemon](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:ways_to_disable_gradle_daemon). It lists several ways to disable it, but keep in mind that this will decrease performance for repeated invocations.

The simplest way is to run with `--no-daemon` or to add `org.gradle.daemon=false` to your `gradle.properties` file.